# Simple Javascript Gallery - Thumbnails won't align to center

Tags: javascript, html, css, gallery

I have followed a tutorial from my University course to make a simple Javascript gallery. Everything on the page aligns to the center apart from the thumbnails. I have tried numerous code to sort it but nothing works. Even 1 thumbnail doesnt align.

http://www.imagebam.com/image/e00d83368784836

Here is the html:

```
            <div id="gallery">

                        <div id="homegallimage">
                            <img id="1" src="../images/homegallery/1.jpg" alt="Web Site Example 1" />
                        </div>

                        <ul id="thumbnails">
                            <li><img src="../images/homegallery/1.jpg" alt="Web Site Example 1" class="thumbnail"></li>
                            <li><img src="../images/homegallery/2.jpg" alt="Web Site Example 2" class="thumbnail"></li>
                            <li><img src="../images/homegallery/3.jpg" alt="Web Site Example 3" class="thumbnail"></li>
                            <li><img src="../images/homegallery/4.jpg" alt="Web Site Example 4" class="thumbnail"></li>
                            <li><img src="../images/homegallery/5.jpg" alt="Web Site Example 5" class="thumbnail"></li>
                            <li><img src="../images/homegallery/6.jpg" alt="Web Site Example 6" class="thumbnail"></li>
                            <li><img src="../images/homegallery/7.jpg" alt="Web Site Example 7" class="thumbnail"></li>
                            <li><img src="../images/homegallery/8.jpg" alt="Web Site Example 8" class="thumbnail"></li>
                            <li><img src="../images/homegallery/9.jpg" alt="Web Site Example 9" class="thumbnail"></li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
    .content
{
    color: #000;
    background-color:#fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.thumbnail 
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    border: solid 4px #6ed8f2;
}

#thumbnails li 
{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#homegallimage img
{
    border: solid 8px #6ed8f2;
}
```

And this is the JavaScript:

```
    // changes source on image to that provided within the thumbnail image tag
function showPic(i_element) {
  var source = i_element.getAttribute("src") ;
  var alt = i_element.getAttribute("alt") ;

  var i = document.createElement("img") ;
  i.setAttribute("src",source) ;
  i.setAttribute("alt",alt) ;

  var placeholder = document.getElementById("homegallimage") ;
  //alert(placeholder.childNodes.length) ;
  placeholder.removeChild(placeholder.childNodes[0]); 
  placeholder.appendChild(i) ;

}

//  add the onclick event to the DOM
function addImages() {
    var item = document.getElementById("thumbnails").getElementsByTagName("img") ;
    for (var i=0 ; i<item.length ; i++) {
      item[i].onmouseover = function() {showPic(this) ; } ;
    }

}

//  specifies the method to run onload
window.onload = addImages ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the ul a width of 920px then give it "margin:auto;" this should align it in the centre. To centrally align something you will need to specify the width of its container.

Comment: That's unusual that should definitely work. In the code you pasted in the question you haven't got any rules for "ul#thumbnails"

Comment: I took it out before posting because it done nothing.

Tried it again when you posted but still does nothing. I just dont understand how everything else on my page (banner, navbar, the gallary main image) all is centered, its just the thumbnails that aren't. :(

Comment: Do you have a working link to the code or a jsfiddle? so I could take a closer look and try and help out.

Comment: try this - http://jsfiddle.net/alexjamest/kffm88gv/ when you implement this into your site you will have to modify severa things as I have added widths & heights so it displays properly in the viewport on jsfiddle. you'll need to change: `ul#thumbnails{width:your specified width for thumbnails wrapper;}` `#homegallimage {width:your specified large image width"}`   `#homegallimage img{height: remove this}`

Comment: Perfect, as standard the user agent stylesheet will give any ul 40px of padding to the left (to give space for bullet point indentation). If you remove this with: `ul#thumbnails {padding: 0;}` it should work

Comment: Thanks Alex. But the padding: 0; doesn't work either. :(

And I implemented your code from your jsfiddle and changed the appropriate code but same thing. Thumbnails not centered. 

7hrs I have been trying to get this to center. Looks like I will just have to leave it as is. Other students in my class have the same code but theirs work. So dunno what is happening here. lol

Comment: I've figured it out, you need to copy and paste this code and add it to your stylesheet - `ul#thumbnails {
padding: 0;
text-align: justify;
width: 916px;
margin: 10px auto;
}`

Comment: It took a whie but I'm glad we got there!