# Form will not center

Tags: html, css

A few days ago I had the problem of having a gallery where the main image would center but the thumbnails would not ..... see here:

[Simple Javascript Gallery - Thumbnails won't align to center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277307/simple-javascript-gallery-thumbnails-wont-align-to-center)

This was answered though not a perfect solution as when I add or take away a thumbnail it all goes into a mess.

Anyway, I now have made a form and this has the same problem .... it is off center. And nothing I try works.

Here is a screenshot:
http://www.imagebam.com/image/33d801369818300

Here is a link to my online page so you can view the source:

http://mayar.abertay.ac.uk/~1301850/strategix/html/contact.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements in #contact are wider than the parents width (300px). Just change the width of #contact from 300px to 354px and it will be centered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
#contact {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
}
```

But your form width near 365px